# Clearcase: Activity dependencies for integration stream merging (patches)

Tags: clearcase

We have a patch model where we're intending on using `cset.pl -findmerge <activity>` to selectively merge cumulative activities to a patch stream (integration stream to integration stream).  Note that we're using a single stream model; although support for teams working with their own dev stream would be supported (i.e. when they join a project they would be working with the integration by default).

However there's the issue of activity dependencies we're trying to solve.

So say you have `integration stream A`,

```
file a.txt    
-> Change 1 (baselined ReleaseA)-> Change 2 -> Change 3  

fileb.txt  
-> Change 1 (baselined ReleaseA)-> Change 2
```

an integration stream B and the config. manager decides they want to include "`Change 3`" in a new patch (patch integration stream - integration stream C).
They perform a `cset.pl fetchmerge` against `Change 3` (which includes changes for `Change 2`).
`Change 2` for `fileb` does not get picked up so **the issue is identifying these activity dependencies**.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The deliver activity can take place between any 2 streams, including integration stream to integration  stream. Any reason why a simple `deliver -act` is not possible here?

Comment: I tryed a "cleartool -act Test2@\TestProjVOB -stream Proj2_Integration@\TestProjVOB -target Proj1_Integration@\TestProjVOB", and it complains about "a deliver operation from integration stream must specify baselines to deliver".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use a variety of cctool commands to view current version in view and pushed it into a script to get a list of activity dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If `Change3` is a rebase/deliver activity you can use

`%ct lsact -contrib Change3`
to get a list of contributing activities
and then traverse any of the rebase/deliver activites listed as contributing
activities to trace if any of them has `Change2` as the contributing activity.

Also assuming that the foundation baseline for the patch stream is the one used for `RelaseA`,shouldn't you need to list activities from `Change1` onwards when you do the merge ?

i.e shouldn't your findmerge invocation be something like

`%findmerge ... Change2,Change3 -fcsets ...`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I should have specified that the streams were integration streams. so those commands don't seem to work

Comment: the command `ct lsact -contrib <activity>` would work immaterial of whether the stream is integration stream or not. Probably you didn't specify the PVOB. The invocation should be something like:
%cleartool lsact -contrib activity@PVOB.

Comment: Says "error: activity <activity>  is not a deliver or rebase integration activity

Comment: Note the problem refers to essentially a single stream model and so deliver and rebase are irrelevant. Even with the multi stream model -contrib only provides activities associated with a single deliver operation, and not the dependencies between a particular baseline(branch point) and an activity

Answer (score 0):

Note (in addition to [sateesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205261/clearcase-activity-dependencies/2205473#2205473)), a `deliver -act Chaange3` (instead of a findmerge) would list `Change2` and `Change1` as activities to include in your deliver.
It would pick up on those dependent activities, probably following an algorithm close to the one described by [sateesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58220/sateesh).

See "[About activity dependencies in the deliver operation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_activity_depend.htm)"

[alt text http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/images/deliver_depnd.gif](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/images/deliver_depnd.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I'll just edit the question again.