# Clearcase equivalent of git no fast forward merge

Tags: clearcase

What is the Clearcase equivalent of git's no fast forward (--no-ff) switch? Or how can I achieve the same functionality?

**BACKGROUND**

The situation is we are running multiple release branches and we need to be able to pull a feature or defect fix from the release branch if required. Currently (and I'm not the one managing Clearcase) all defect work is checked directly into the release branch, so backing out changes is time-consuming and potentially error-prone.

When using git with --no-ff, I can back out a feature or defect very quickly with minimal chance of causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In ClearCase, you would instead cancel an [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205499/6309) (if you are using ClearCase UCM), or cancelling merges for a set of files with [negative merges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309).

But there is no notion of "fast-forward": there is no HEAD to move, only versions ([file by file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)) to merge. So if you know the merged versions, you can create new versions which cancel them (that is what the negative merge does).

Answer (score -1):

There is no ff but there is also no HEAD in clearcase in the sense of git. The workflow is different. You always check in your code to a new checkin (or commit in git terminology). So it is like you are always doing a merge commit